# Why use List Box Item? Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am wondering why use ListBoxItem inside a ListBox? I found when I am doing databinding and such you don't need ListBoxItem and in some cases I found it worked better without it.

What is the reason for it? Is it just for hardcoded stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you don't use `ListBoxItem` (and you're right, there is not much reason to use it to define the items), the `ListBox` control still uses it.  Namely, it uses it to wrap the data template of each item in the list.  One time you might have occasion to refer to it in your XAML code, is when styling the item container -- which you accomplish using `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

The above is a common example, because if you want the items in your ListBox to stretch out horizontally, you have to use that approach.  (Setting the item DataTemplate to stretch, by itself, will not work, because the containing ListBoxItem is left-aligned by default.)

---

Here's a full example.

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Letters}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Green">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"  Foreground="White" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <!-- 
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        -->
    </ListBox>
```

This appears as follows:

[image: Without ItemContainerStyle applied]

Uncomment the `ItemContainerStyle`, and it appears as follows:

[image: With ItemContainerStyle]

Comment: Sorry, Can you show pictures of the difference, I am using a template right now(I dragged by data source in with Blend to generate the data, then I edited the current item template, I wrapped stack panels around some other controls and it seems fine)

Comment: @chobo2 I made a mistake -- it should have been `HorizontalContentAlignment`, not `HorizontalAlignment`.  Anyway, I updated above with an example, so you can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Hey, I see what you mean but I am referring to why would you actually drag/write "  <ListBoxItem Content="ListBoxItem" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>" in the ItemTemplate. It seems like your manipulating the wrapping it puts on.

Comment: @chobo2 yes, exactly.  I was basically agreeing with you, that there's no sense to writing `ListBoxitem` inside the ItemTemplate.